# Game recommndation: Ancient rome

Tags: game

I am looking for a game set in the classic Roman Empire.

I Like turn by turn, and 4x games, however I am open to other suggestions.

It could be a Civilization type game, or Sim-City like, or a war game, but I will try anything,

I hope that's not too vague.

o/s : Windows 10 (although I could run others in a VM for a really good game)
price: under one million Euros

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest Rome Total War and Rome Total War 2.

The Total War series are turn by turn strategies, with a real time component in the combat phase(which can be skipped). Both of these games are set in ancient Rome and have good reviews. Personally I have played Rome Total War and found it interesting.

Comment: Please add some info *why* you recommend these.

Answer (score 2):

Anything by Sid Meier...

However, I'll specifically mention 0 A.D.  Both Free (libre) and free (gratis), open source.  https://play0ad.com/

From their page -

> “0 A.D.” is a time period that never actually existed: In the usual
>   calendar, one goes from 1 B.C. to 1 A.D. and skips zero. This reflects
>   the historical fiction in the game: Who would have won if all the
>   factions were pitted against each other when each of them was at its
>   prime?
>
> We intend to portray some of the major civilizations over the
>   millennium of 500 B.C. to 500 A.D. (Hence the midpoint, zero.) That is
>   an ambitious prospect, so in the first edition of 0 A.D. we focus on
>   the last five centuries B.C. Perhaps in future expansion packs, more
>   civilizations will be added, along with additional gameplay features.
>
> We put a strong emphasis on historical accuracy while developing 0
>   A.D. We plan all our units and all our buildings based on
>   reconstructions of how the units and the buildings might have looked
>   like in the ancient world. We even name them in the original
>   languages, such as Greek and Latin. But it’s worth remembering that
>   any game should be fun to play, so, in many cases, we preferred
>   playability over historical accuracy.

Comment: Looks OK (+1), but it's still in Alpha and not specifically Roman. I will give it a try, though